# Numpy two matrices, pairwise dot product of rows

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, dot-product

We are currently working on a python project and have to vectorize a lot due to performance constraints. We end up with the following calculation: We have two numpy arrays of shape `(20,6)` and want to calculate the pairwise dot product of the rows, i.e. we should obtain a `(20,1)` matrix in the end, where each row is the scalar obtained by the respective vector dot multiplication.

Comment: Yes, and what is your question? What problem are you experiencing with your attempt at doing this?

Answer (score 10):

You can multiply the two arrays element wise and then do sum by rows, and then you have an array where each element is a dot product from rows of the two original arrays:

```
a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
b = np.array([[3,4], [2,1]])

(a * b).sum(axis=1)
# array([11, 10])
```

Comment: That did it, thanks!